# Can this equation of permutation be true$?$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

Find the value of $k$ if

### $${}^{k+3}_{}P^{}_{k+1}=\frac{11(k-1)}{2}\cdot{}^{k+3}_{}P^{}_{k}$$

I found the value of $k$ as $\displaystyle\frac{17}{11}$ but is it right$?$

Can the laws of permutation be applied on rational numbers$?$ Aren't we going into Gamma function$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can define falling factorials to work for arbitrary base numbers if you like, though the number of iterations must still be a whole number so this would still imply you are looking for a whole number $k$.  I agree with your result which implies that there is no such $k$.